# Logging requests to server in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: logging, request, cakephp-3.0

I have a site running on CakePHP 3 and I need to implement a logger in order to log some info about requests that are hitting the server. I need all the basic information for GET and POST requests, plus the query parameters or the payload.
I've seen the [Logging article in Cake's Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html). The problem is that the example provided there it's not enough for me to implement what I need.

Should I use some kind of middleware that intercept the requests and then call a logger? 
Could you point to some resource that gives a more detailed example of how to implement a custom log engine in Cake 3?